# nested function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, function, scope, nested

Hey I'm new to javascript and I can't get the nested function to work, I just don't understand why. Is there problem with scope? thx a lot

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var prepocet = function(smer, poradie, pocet_obrazkov) {

    if (smer == "left") {
        if (pozicia - 1 < 1) {
            return pocet_obrazkov
        } else {
            return pozicia - 1
        };
    } else {
        if (pozicia + 1 > pocet_obrazkov) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return pocet_obrazkov + 1
        };
    };
  };

  $("body").on("click", ".arrow", function() {
    var smer = "left"
    var pocet_obrazkov = $(this).parent().parent().next(".seria").children().length;
    var pozicia = $(this).parent().parent().next(".seria").children().index(".on") + 1;


    if ($(this).hasClass("arrow left")) {
        smer = "left"
    } else {
        smer = "right"
    };

    var nova_pozicia = prepocet(smer, poradie, pocet_obrazkov);


    $(this).parent().parent().next().children('#iddv img:nth-child(' + pozicia + ')').hide().addClass("off").removeClass("on");
    $(this).parent().parent().next().children('#iddv img:nth-child(' + nova_pozicia + ')').show().addClass("on").removeClass("off");

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the JavaScript console for errors. My guess is you'll see there something with `undefined`: The function parameter name is `poradie` but in the function, you use `pozicia`. Further down, in a different scope, you define `pozicia` but `prepocet()` can't see that.

Comment: You are right, thank you! how could I not see that my variable names are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a scope problem, you need to move the declaration of `prepocet` outside of the `$(document).ready()` function because that is where the function exists.